# Send Django Form as JSON via AJAX

Tags: python, json, ajax, django, forms

I am working on project in Django 1.8.8 and I need to convert a django form into a JSON format so I can send it to the browser via an AJAX call.

I found this package ( https://github.com/WiserTogether/django-remote-forms ) which is no more available on Pypi. Beside it's 2 years old since the last commit.

Would you please give me some advice on what to do or which package to use ?

Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: Can you give a little more info? What do you plan on doing with the form once you receive it from the AJAX call? Does it have to be in JSON, or would the form rendered as HTML work?

Comment: You need to be clearer in your own mind about what you are doing.  The Django form is code that runs on the server. What does it actually mean to "convert it to JSON format and send it to the browser" ?  Do you mean you will post the form _from_ the browser to your server, then you want Django to _reply_ with a JSON-formatted response?

Comment: Sorry if I wasn't clear enough. What I am trying to do is to convert a Form to a JSON, so I can print it in the client side. The reason is to force a user to login after performing a specific action if he's not authenticated. I hope my explanation will be more explicit.

Answer (score 2):

The two main things you could do are:

- Render the form to an HTML string, and send that.
- Create a JSON object, from which the HTML can be constructed.

Here's an example of how you could turn a form object into json:

```
import json
def form_to_json(form):
    result = {}
    for name, field in form.fields.iteritems():
        result[name] = field_to_dict(field)
    return json.dumps(result)

def field_to_dict(field):
    return {
        "type": field.__class__.__name__,
        "widget_type": field.widget.__class__.__name__,
        "hidden": field.widget.is_hidden,
        "required": field.widget.is_required,
        "label": field.label,
        "help_text": field.help_text,
        "min_length": field.min_length, # optional
        "max_length": field.max_length, # optional
        "initial_value": field.initial,
    }
```

If you also want to handle error messages server side, you should probably include that information in `field_to_dict` as well.

To render a form as html, just convert it to a string.

Comment: Wow! Thanks a lot. I'm going to give a try. I let you know. Thanks again.

Comment: @bigblind Could you please check my answer related to it? Thanks in advance

Answer (score -1):

```
<script>
var data = $("#form_id").serialize()
$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: url,
  data: data,
  success: success,
  dataType: dataType
});
</script>
```

I guess... maybe... its really not clear what you are asking