# why i use enctype='application/json' but CONTENT_TYPE still be application/x-www-form-urlencoded

Tags: json, django, forms, templates, post

```
<form enctype='application/json' action="{% url 'xxx'  %}" method="post">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <input type='number' name='bottle-on-wall' value='1'>
    <input type='number' name='bottle-on-wall' value='2'>
    <input type='number' name='bottle-on-wall' value='3'>
    <button type="submit">send</button>
</form>
```

`CONTENT_TYPE   'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'`

how can i send the form data as json to server

Comment: May be this link will be helped you. [click here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36288922/send-django-form-as-json-via-ajax)

Comment: That's not one of the valid options, so you get the invalid value default; read e.g. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLFormElement/enctype.

Comment: @jonrsharpe so i have to write the js code use ajax to send the form data as json?

Comment: You cannot send it as JSON directly from an HTML form, certainly. Whether you have options beyond that (use JS, send _not_-JSON) depends on your constraints.

Answer (score 0):

use `multipart/form-data`

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/form#enctype

```html
<form enctype='multipart/form-data' action="{% url 'xxx'  %}" method="post">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <input type='number' name='bottle-on-wall' value='1'>
    <input type='number' name='bottle-on-wall' value='2'>
    <input type='number' name='bottle-on-wall' value='3'>
    <button type="submit">send</button>
</form>
```